# Serendipity with multiplicity? Composite Primary Key of 2 Foreign Keys in EF throws error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using Entity Framework 4.0 with Database First and come across the following problem.
I have the following tables (simplified for visual purposes)

Table B contains a  Composite Primary Key of 2 Foreign Keys.

SQL Server Tables A,B,C

```
A            B                 C
A_ID(PK)<----A_ID(PK)(FK)      C_ID(PK)
             C_ID(PK)(FK)------^
```

When I update my model,

I see the relationships in my model browser but for some reason Table B looks like:

```
A            B                 C
A_ID(PK)<----A_ID(PK)(FK)      C_ID(PK)
             C_ID(FK)----------^
```

and i get the following error:

Error   36  Error 113: Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'B' in relationship 'FK_B_A'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be 1. C:......MyDatabase.edmx 3776  11  MyABCProject

This one is worth your morning cup of coffee becoming cold.

Thanks alot!

Comment: Does table B have the two FKs, and the PK defined? Does it have any extra fields?

Comment: yes and Table B has other fields as well, some foreign keys

Comment: does yout table appear in your model or only a relationship between A and C?

Comment: model browser shows both relationships A-B and B-C , but only one primary key is showing in table B, the composite is ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto the model browser and add C_ID to your A_ID thus creating a Composite Primary key.